# Chill wind or Chilly wind

Tags: word-usage

> A **Chill/Chilly** wind blew and icy fingers of death crept up my spine.

Which is correct to use here ? Chill or Chilly ?

*Chill wind* is a [idiom](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/chill-wind-of-sth) which means troubles, difficulties etc but since we want to convey that the wind was cold so using chilly is correct but  someone [here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/3754080) said that they both mean the same. Is it correct ? *Chill* is a noun so I don't think it can be used to qualify wind, instead *chilly* is a adjective so *chilly* should be the correct word to use. Am I correct ?

Comment: Either is fine, but as you say, "a chill wind" is more poetic.

Comment: ***Chill*** is fine as an adjectival usage in many contexts - [a chill look](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+chill+look%22), for example. It's a bit "poetic", but not really "dated".

Comment: In the sentence quoted, given the "icy fingers of death", the most appropriate is probably "chill". But in regular conversation people would not say "a chill wind".

Comment: Note that "chill" and "chilly" have different nuances. They don't really mean the same thing, except broadly speaking.

Comment: Strange. I've never come across 'chill' in this context. Is it American?

Comment: @marcellothearcane  not especially.   I searched and found it in one of Oscar Wilde's plays, and I think he'd (cleverly) object to being called an *American* anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robusto points out, "a *chill* wind" is not the same thing as "a *chilly* wind".  *Chilly* means relatively cold, or at least enough to make you shiver.  *Chill* implies a deeper and more *dramatic* cold, which is why it's generally used as a metaphor, as an omen of troubles to come.

In the context you provide, "a chill wind" is more appropriate -- although be aware that a story with too many of these dramatic phrases can feel *melodramatic* rather than ominous.

In a different context, or used differently, both *chill* and *chilly* mean the same thing.

> I feel a chill, could you close the window?
>
> It's chilly in here, could you close the window?

Comment: How about a super idiomatic "chill wind" that isn't like those other, ya know, super serious uptight winds. It's chill.

Comment: @KatrinaBrock that is exactly what I thought of when I read "chill wind." I would never describe wind as "chill" to mean "cold." It's either "chilly," or there is "a chill," as in Andrew's example sentence above. Personally I think calling that phrase poetic is downplaying how weird it is.

Comment: @cjl750 Weird perhaps, but it's pretty ubiquitous in English literature.

Comment: @KatrinaBrock  here in San Diego, it's, like, *chill* winds are the only kind of winds we get.

Comment: @Andrew I think it is safe to say we are not reading the same literature then :)

Comment: @cjl750  To be clear: In a brief search I found that Charles Dickens and Oscar Wilde both used the expression, although not in their most well-known works.  You might prefer to read other stuff (as do I) but I think of them as "literary" authors.

Comment: @Andrew I am not surprised to hear that those authors used the phrase, and I am not gonna sit back and say you won't hear the phrase "in English literature." But I would be interested to hear others' opinions on if they actually hear anyone use "chill" (*not* "chilly") as an adjective that means "cold" rather than "relaxed" these days. I would go so far as to call it unidiomatic in 2017, but maybe that's just me. Still, OP's example sentence is pretty poetic, so I think it could work just fine in that very specific context.

Comment: @cjl750 [Not so very unusual](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/02/opinion/campaign-stops/a-chill-wind-blows.html), I think.  Also [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/15/science/feeling-a-chill-blame-the-polar-vortex-and-global-warming.html), and references in *Newsweek* and various other publications in the past 18 months.  Naturally these writers use the expression for dramatic effect.